# Does the Primal Companion Hunter archetype require that you choose Unchained evolutions in PFS?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pathfinder-society

The original summoner class is banned in Pathfinder Society. As per [Additional Resources](http://paizo.com/pathfinderSociety/rpg/additional):

> As of 4/27/15 the summoner class in this book is no longer legal for play. A summoner character that has played at least once at level 2 or higher by this date qualfies to continue using this version of the class. Otherwise, only the summoner in Pathfinder RPG Pathfinder Unchained is legal for play.

The feat [Evolved Familiar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/evolved-familiar/) and the [Primal Companion Hunter](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/hunter/archetypes/paizo---hunter-archetypes/primal-companion-hunter/) archetype are both legal, and both allow you to choose eidolon evolutions.

Nothing in the Additional Resources, Campaign Clarifications, or relevant FAQs say anything about these resources using unchained evolutions rather than original evolutions.

Is there something I'm missing somewhere that says that options similar to these have to use the unchained summoner options for PFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It uses the Unchained Eidolon evolutions, but...

... the requirements for eidolon subtypes are to be ignored.

This is a new, recently given official ruling, as found [here](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2topw?PFS-summoner-related-feats#6).

> For the Evolved Familiar feat, use evolutions for the unchained summoner (Pathfinder RPG Pathfinder Unchained 25). The familiar must conform to all requirements listed in the evolution, such as having wings to take wing buffet, with the following exception. If any of the eidolon subtypes that appear in Pathfinder Unchained qualify for the evolution, then a familiar qualifies for that evolution as well.

The linked posts states that the above statement will be added to the [Campaign Clarifications](http://paizo.com/pathfinderSociety/rpg/clarifications) document in the near future.

**Note:** This ruling is specific to the Evolved Familiar feat. However, it is quite likely that it will apply to the other similar options as well.

Comment: I have to point out that only the Evolve Familiar feat was [addressed](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2topw?PFS-summoner-related-feats#6). The answer should make that clear to the reader.

Comment: @ShadowKras I did say that in my answer. I'll edit above to bold it or something, I guess, so that others don't miss it.

Comment: Might want to change the bolded title to make clear that the "it" is referring to the feat.